# How to bundle an FMU with a png-file that illustrates the system?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, fmi

I use FMU a lot for simulation of Modelica models in a Python environment. It would be nice to bundle the obtained FMU from compilation with a png-file that shows the system. Is that possible?

And how to access that png-file and show it in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Can you please explain it further.  Is the .png used as an icon image or something related?

Comment: I mainly think of a process diagram showing the configuration with icons of components and connections that illustrate the system the FMU simulates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the input from Christian and Dag and reading about package zipfile
https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open
we can handle the problem as follows for FMU (2.0):

1. Create a file 'processDiagram.png' by for instance a screenshot of the Modelica-configuration.
2. Unzip the FMU.
3. Place the png-file in a folder called "documentation" at the top  in parallell to the modelDescription-xml file. If the folder is not there you create one.
4. Zip the FMU and name it for example: 'fmu_model.fmu'

The person who receive this FMU can now do the following in Python  to show the process_diagram.png

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
import zipfile

fmu_file = zipfile.ZipFile('fmu_model.fmu', 'r')
process_diagram = fmu_file.open('documentation/processDiagram.png')
plt.imshow(img.imread(process_diagram))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

For a safe handling we need to also include a system with checksum or similar to avoid the possibility
to corrupt the FMU with wrong png-files.  Design of this safety handling I leave to the designers of PyFMI and FMPy. In fact FMPy has some general handling of checksum already for FMI 2.0, but to my knowledge no functionality to extract a process_diagram file.

Comment: For FMI 2.0, the top level model.png should be the icon; I would place the "process diagram" in the documentation folder.

Comment: I have updated the code. First I understood model.png as the processDiagram.png, but I can understand there can be a need for a "simplified" icon for the FMU in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

For FMI 3.0.1:
There is a standardized place and name in the documentation folder for a diagram picture
https://fmi-standard.org/docs/3.0.1/#structure-of-zip
[image]
Additionally you can place an icon in the  TerminalsAndIcons Folder, but this is not intended for the diagram.

For FMI 2.0.4 a location for a diagram picture is not standardized, but you could still place it in the documentation folder, see section 2.3 of https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/releases/download/v2.0.4/FMI-Specification-2.0.4.pdf
[image]

It is up to the importing tool how to display or make the the concentent of the documentation folder available.

For FMI 3.0 you could ask the creators of your FMI-import-toolbox (fmpy? pyfmi?)to provide an access function for the diagram.png

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The file model.png should perhaps not be seen as processDiagram.png, which I first though. Code updated. Hope I understand also you Tzane right.

Answer (score 0):

In Dymola you can export an FMU with an automatically generated icon containing either the icon layer or the diagram layer from Dymola. Inside the FMU there is a top-level directory `terminalsAndIcons`.

If I remember correctly, this is a new feature in FMI 3; see the specification for details.

Comment: I guess the idea to include a process diagram  in the FMU is both new and old!  The other day I googled up a document by some key people from 2010 ,v that exactly describes what I was looking for, see ref 4 slide 5 at the Wikipedia site  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Mock-up_Interface Here is suggested that you just include a png-file in parallell with the modelDescription.xml file in the zip-file.  When I manually just include a png-file in this way in an FMU made by JModelica, I find I can still run the FMU both with PyFMI and FMPy (all in Windows).

Comment: Question is if here is some other recommendation where to put it, in FMI 2.0 or FMI 3.0. Here must be some rules for protection of  FMU-integrity today?

Comment: What I am looking for now is some simple way in Python to extract the png-file from the fmu (zip-file) without need to pack it up and re-zip it. Here seems to be some different techniques around. How to print the png-file is easy using package matplotlib.image.

Comment: Dag, is the folder terminalsAndIcons just parallell to folder binaries?

Comment: Answer updated to answer the folder question.